# How to use server side validation on button click using Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have 2 buttons on my page and i want to validate only on btnSubmit click.  However i don't want to validate if user clicks the btnSave button. I have several text-boxes that i need to validate..

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="** Required **" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txt1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />
```

here is the button save

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClick="btn_Save_Click"> 
<i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Save
```

here is the button submit

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="linkSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click"> 
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Submit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `CauseValidation = "False"` on all the buttons you don't want to trigger validation, including LinkButtons

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkSave" runat="server" CauseValidation="False" />
```

If you want different validations per button, then use the `ValidationGroup="GroupName"` attribute on the button and all the controls participating in that validation (associated to that button)

Answer (score 0):

[Use validation groups.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

This allows you to make one button enforce validation (btnSubmit) but the other not (btnSave).

Answer (score 0):

you can use group validation

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" validationgroup="validTxT1Group" ErrorMessage="** Required **" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txt1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="linkSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btn_Save_Click"> 
<i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Save

<asp:LinkButton ID="linkSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="validTxT1Group" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click"> 
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Submit
```